# Setting Up Category and Forum and Loop it

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm creating a forum software in Django and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to relate the forums table to the categories. I want to display this to the index page:

```
Category 1
 --forum 1
 --forum 2
 --forum 2

Category 2
 --forum 1
 --forum 2
 --forum 3
```

These are my models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Forum(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='forums')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here are my views:

```
class HomeView(ListView):
context_object_name = 'name'
template_name = 'index.html'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['forums'] = Forum.objects.all()
    context['categorys'] = Category.objects.all()
    return context
```

This is what I currently have on the home page, the only problem is, it's simply looping through all the categories and forums. I want the category to be looped in the first for loop, and in the second one to pull all the forums that belong to that category.

```
{% for category in categorys %}
   --code
   {% for forum in forums %}
     --code
   {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

How do I fix this so that it displays properly and the relation is correct? A category can have many forums but a forum can only have one category. So a one-to-many relationship I believe.

~Thanks,
Taz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple:

```
{% for category in categorys %}
   {{ category.name }}
   {% for forum in category.forums.all %}
     {{ forum.name }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, you do not need to pass `forums` through context variable(via `get_context_data` method).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Also, how is it that I can access category.forums even though the category model doesn't have a forum object?

Comment: Its reverse relationship between Category to Forum. They are called related objects.